# Animated Node does not exist with tag 1

Tags: react-native, expo, react-animated

We recently updated to Expo SDK 40 and now have run into a issue with “React Native: Animated Node with tag 1 does not exist”.

This is only an error on Android that is occurring.

We’ve changed all instances of `useNativeDriver` to `false`.

We’ve also tried commenting out all instances of `Animated` in our code and the error still persists.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer because I'm sure there was a fix for SDK 40 but Expo SDK 41 came out today and figured I'd see if that fixed the issue and it did.

For anyone that is stuck.  SDK 41 using `expo upgrade` might be your solution.